# What are the differents between USE | select_db function or TABLENAME.dbo?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I'm using mssql and PHP and I wanna know what are the differents 
between changing database with the function mssql_change_db, or to add USE [DB_NAME] in the start of the query or to add DB_NAME.dbo.tablename in every query? 
For example, I have database named "LogsDB" 
So, what's the better way to execute query with database switching.

---

Like this? :

```
mssql_select_db("LogsDB", $this -> sqlHandle);
mssql_query("select top 1 username from changePW");
```

---

Or like this? :

```
mssql_query("USE [LogsDB] select top 1 username from changePW");
```

---

Or like this? : 
`mssql_query("select top 1 username from LogsDB.dbo.changePW");` 
In this way, the database will be changed only for this query, and it's nice. 
Is there another way to set database not to change but to execute query to it?

---

If there are more ways to switch databases, and they are better than what I said here, I'll be happy to hear about them.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 'DB_NAME.dbo.tablename'. You would use this when you are querying multiple databases in a query.'USE DB' can be defined at the top of the query page but as you say, it only applies for that query

Comment: Biggest thing to note is that `mssql_select_db()` is deprecated and is removed from php7 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-select-db.php

Comment: Also you can specify the default DB to user which is working with SQL Server. When you don't specify the DB - it uses default DB from user prefs.

Comment: Is there anythign else you are looking for?

Comment: No, thank you for answering me :)

Comment: I posted an answer below. If that helps below, please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mssql_query("select top 1 username from LogsDB.dbo.changePW");
```

I think the above is the best way to select a database especially, if you will be querying multiple databases. Its always a good practice

```
DatabaseName.Schema.TableName
```

There are also time when you have to query across different servers. In those situations

```
ServerName.DatabaseName.Schema.TableName
```

It just provides you with more felexibility. In my opinion, this is the best way to do it.

Hope it helps.